# Best way to move ubuntu to a new drive in dual boot setup with multiple drives?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Setup is an SSD with Windows + Shared EFI partition and a hard drive with Ubuntu install. The problem is that the hard drive is way too slow for a usable experience.

So the plan is to add a new SSD to my system and use ubuntu installer to install a new Ubuntu OS. How many live Ubuntu installations do I have now? 2 or 1? Can I just delete the old EXT4 partitions on the hard drive I
m not using?

Main thing I'm confused/worried about is how the EFI partition changes.

Thanks

Also wanted to clarify everything is UEFI on my system.

Update: Things work fine with one EFI partition as I've found:

1. Ran USB Installer for 20.04
2. Selected 'Something Else' option
3. Chose the Windows SSD for bootloader
4. Partitioned new drive
5. Ran Installer as normal
6. My GRUB menu has both Ubuntu installs + Windows
7. I deleted the old Ubuntu partitions and reclaimed the space in Windows
8. Ran update-grub to remove menu option for Ubuntu install that no longer exists
9. Deleted old swap space entry in /etc/fstab that no longer exists

Comment: Make sure you have backups of anything you cannot afford to lose. I like Macrium Reflect Free for backups of Windows stuff. If you are worried about breaking your EFI partition it’s particularly easy to make and restore a partition backup, just make the rescue environment first. When you install the new Ubuntu I’d expect it to use the existing EFI partition. Once you can boot the new Ubuntu delete the old partitions and update grub. Should be fine but if you hit a problem search on here for an answer first or ask a new question if you cannot resolve it.

Comment: If you are currently booting Windows and Ubuntu using GRUB located on the Windows SSD, create the new SSD partition table the same GPT or MSDOS as the old SSD. Then boot a Live USB, open GParted and right click, copy Ubuntu partition from the old HDD and paste to the new SSD. If you prefer a fresh Ubuntu install unplug the Windows SSD. Install Ubuntu to the new SSD in the same Legacy/UEFI mode Windows boots in. When done plug Windows SSD back in, boot Ubuntu and update-grub.

Comment: I always suggest new install and restore from your normal backup. Proves backup has everything your need with old drive still available to add to backup if needed. Does major house clean of old logs & other cruft. I like to have ESP on Ubuntu drive, but Ubiquity will only install to first drive's ESP. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition, but some still like one:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: @C.S.Cameron If I unplug the windows SSD, the EFI partition will be missing, and Ubuntu installer will create a fresh one. So when I plug Windows SSD back in I'll have two EFI partitions's. Isn't this something I don't want?

Comment: I don't have any important files on my Ubuntu OS. So I just plan on rerunning the Ubuntu installer and hoping that GRUB will get patched with the new install (on EFI on the Windows SSD) without any specific steps different than a normal install. Then I can delete the old HDD EXT4 partitions to reclaim the space. This sorta sounds like what @PonJar is implying to do (besides backing up beforehand as well).

Comment: There is no problem if both disks have their own EFI partitions. Full install USB's all have their own boot partitions and work fine. If you remove the Windows drive while making the Ubuntu drive it is impossible to break. To patch GRUB with the new install just run `sudo update-grub`. This will work as long as both installs are either Legacy or both UEFI. But not mixed Legacy - UEFI.

Comment: If you have an EFI on both SSDs you will always have one working OS in the case of a disk failure. An EFI on the new disk will boot both Windows and Ubuntu so you can leave the original untouched if you want.